# python social app (django) - properly save/retrieve user

Tags: django, web-applications, django-models, django-socialauth, python-social-auth

I'm experimenting with python social auth for my django project and I'm having some trouble understanding the easiest - most straightforward way of creating/saving/retrieving users once logged (eg. via google).

I notice that when logging in through, lets say, gmail - an entry is created in the social auth/Users table. However; the Auth/Users table only has one entry at a time(the person who is logged in).

Now my social auth pipeline goes something like this

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.mail.mail_validation',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'path.to.my.own',
)
```

So as you can see I have my own pipeline handler at the very end which I can use to extract more information.

I guess i'm just confused as I do not see many examples online on what is the best way/best practice of storing and retrieving social logged in users from the DB?  Should I just extract the social auth user's name,email, etc from the pipeline and create my own model or is this already provided somehow? I guess just to rephrase the question for clarity: Does python social auth for django contain a model for that user social auth table that we can use?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused on how python-social-auth works when you click the `login` button/link in your site. If there's a user logged in, the the social account will be associated to that user, but if nobody is logged in, a new user instance will be created (unless the social account was already used in your site).

Python-social-auth integrates with django-auth and also supports custom user models, it doesn't provide a user model just the set of tables to track the social account association.

Comment: I guess that's what im trying to find out...  When the new user instance is made upon social auth how can I use it.  How can i make a foreign key to it; how can I query it from the DB if a model doesn't exist for it.  You mention that it integrates with django's built in user model but as I mentioned above - only one user shows up in the Auth/User's table at any time?